# Pig - Creating groups of a given size

Tags: group-by, apache-pig

```
recs = load 'a.txt';
grp = group recs with each group having 5 records;
```

I need to do something like the above.
So if recs has 10 records, I want the groups to be created so that
each group has 5 records each.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A scalable solution could be to have a **UDF accumulates records** into a new bag and **outputs the bag when it has 5 elements** and empty bag (or null) if it does not have 5 elements yet.

One drawback is that the last group of each map might have less than 5 elements (so can try to pad with nulls or discard/regroup them all).

```
recs = load 'a.txt';
grp_5 = foreach recs generate GROUPER(*, 5) as group;
grp = filter grp by not IsEmpty(group);
```

Edit for comment:

A regular Bag attribute would be good as the UDF is normally [instantiated](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/udf.html#function-instantiation) at the beginning of the map then its exec() is called for each record. Think something like streaming all the records through it like a MAX function.

Comment: So, I will have to use a static variable in the UDF class? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Because of the life cycle of a UDF using a non static attribute should be safer.